# How can I show login popup when user clicks on download button

Tags: plugins, login

I am looking for adding a login popup to my WP page where the I have a download button to download some file. when a user who is not logged in clicks on the download button, I want to show the login/register popup and once user is done logging in, I want go ahead with downloading the file for him. Is there a pluging for that that I can use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let me know you are doing with bootstrap modal or any else ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Popup anything on click](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-anything-on-click/) plugin. It enables you to add highly customizable popup windows. You can insert any type of content into your popup, including HTML codes, image, shortcodes etc.